# Multilanguage database field setup

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

We're looking to create a drupal commerce site with multiple languages for Drupal translated manually stored different translations in a seperate fields. Different fields would be displayed upon changing the language type.

i.e.

> field_title (english) -> field_title_fr (french) -> field_title_gr (german)
>
> field_description (english) -> field_title_fr (french) -> field_title_gr (german)
>
> field_price (english) -> field_price (french)
> -> etc...

- Is it possible to click a link to have the website trigger a language change?
- Also, how could you have drupal display a different field?
- Would this method be the drupal way of doing it ? Or is there a module for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post actually gives insight on how multilanguage fields work using internationalization:
http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-get-field-values-entity-objects-nodes-users-taxonomy

As well as [Gabor's](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-get-field-values-entity-objects-nodes-users-taxonomy) Very authoritative one: http://hojtsy.hu/multilingual-drupal7

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of **internationalization** modules and the list available [here](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).

To trigger a language change you could use a **Language Switcher** module.